# Increase/Decrease the number of Worker Role instances in Azure

Tags: java, azure

I can increase the number of Worker Role (WR) instances directly from Java using the ServiceManagementRest class in the Azure4Java package. See the tutorial [Azure Management through Java](http://www.windowsazure4j.org/learn/java_docs/org/soyatec/windowsazure/management/ServiceManagementRest.html).

My question is, when I decrease the number of WR instances, can I decide which WR instances shut down? Because, for the Cloud elasticity idea, I would stop the instances in a IDLE status and not the instances in EXECUTING status.

Regards,
Fabrizio

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't choose which instance(s) to shut down; you simply change the instance count, and the fabric controller takes care of shutting instances down. One reason is due to fault domains and SLA: if you had, say, 4 instances in 2 fault domains, and shut down two instances in fault domain 0, you'd now have 2 instances in fault domain 1. So now you have two instances in the same rack, perhaps, and that rack goes offline. Now you have zero instances running for a period of time.

Dealing with instance shutdown is a common scenario, and the typical pattern for working around this is by taking advantage of queues to buffer your workload, then have worker role instances consume work items from these queues. If you shut down an instance prior to its work being finished, the item eventually reappears on the queue and another instance can do the work.

This pattern requires idempotency, which is sometimes a challenge. With a recent update to Windows Azure queues, you can now modify queue messages, which makes this a bit easier - you can add information to your queue message as you complete various stages of your work item processing. Then, if your instance is shut down before work is completed, the next worker to pick it up can resume from a point other than "start."

One more detail: you should be able to handle the Stopping event, and tell the "instance being stopped" to stop reading from the queue (maybe set a flag). Then, override OnStop(), and wait for in-process operations to complete before returning. If the still-in-process operations will take more than 5 minutes, you might have to get creative...

Comment: When you said _ This pattern requires idempotency _ mean that each worker can execute any task?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying: An idempotent operation is one that can be repeated with consistent, repeatable results and side-effects. For example: If you were processing a queue message and something happened before completing the processing (maybe it took longer than the message timeout, or the VM crashed). This message would then re-appear on the queue and eventually be processed again. The results should be the same, whether you process the message once or multiple times.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot control which instance will shut down, however it is almost always (as far as I've seen) the instance with the highest number suffix. I.e. if you have IN_0, IN_1 and IN_2 and you close an instance it will most likely be IN_2 that shuts down. Maybe you can use this trend to your advantage?

What is probably least obstructive is if you wait for a time of day when the worker roles are less busy to reduce instances?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's wise to never assume what will happen next is based on an instance id.  I tend to spread roles over services (scaleunits), starting and stopping when required - pattern used to control 4000 nodes.